# gulp serve SyntaxError error ( Angular1.5)

Tags: angularjs, gulp, package.json, angular1.6

I have got below errors after using `gulp serve` to run a Angular project.

> SyntaxError:         /Users/xxxx/Desktop/xxx/Projects/xxxx_Project/TeamTrack_Angular/package.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 1429
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:672:27)
>       at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at module.exports     (/Users/jzhu321/Desktop/PwC/Projects/TeamTrack_Project/TeamTrack_Angular/node_modules/gulp-load-plugins/index.js:49:49)
>       at Object. (/Users/jzhu321/Desktop/PwC/Projects/TeamTrack_Project/TeamTrack_Angular/gulp/build.js:7:37)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)

and this is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "forecastAngular",
"version": "0.1.0",
"dependencies": {
"bower": "^1.7.9",
"browser-sync": "~2.9.11",
"browser-sync-spa": "~1.0.3",
"chalk": "~1.1.1",
"del": "~2.0.2",
"eslint-plugin-angular": "~0.12.0",
"estraverse": "~4.1.0",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-angular-filesort": "~1.1.1",
"gulp-angular-templatecache": "~1.8.0",
"gulp-autoprefixer": "~3.0.2",
"gulp-cssnano": "~2.1.1",
"gulp-eslint": "~1.0.0",
"gulp-filter": "~3.0.1",
"gulp-flatten": "~0.2.0",
"gulp-htmlmin": "~1.3.0",
"gulp-inject": "~3.0.0",
"gulp-load-plugins": "~0.10.0",
"gulp-ng-annotate": "~1.1.0",
"gulp-protractor": "~2.1.0",
"gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
"gulp-replace": "~0.5.4",
"gulp-rev": "~6.0.1",
"gulp-rev-replace": "~0.4.2",
"gulp-sass": "~2.0.4",
"gulp-size": "~2.0.0",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.6.0",
"gulp-uglify": "~1.4.1",
"gulp-useref": "~3.0.3",
"gulp-util": "~3.0.6",
"http-proxy-middleware": "~0.9.0",
"karma": "~0.13.10",
"karma-angular-filesort": "~1.0.0",
"karma-coverage": "~0.5.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~0.3.6",
"karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.2.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.1",
"karma-phantomjs-shim": "~1.2.0",
"lodash": "~3.10.1",
"main-bower-files": "~2.9.0",
"phantomjs": "~1.9.18",
"uglify-save-license": "~0.4.1",
"wiredep": "~2.2.2",
},
"scripts": {
"test": "gulp test",
"postinstall": "bower install",
"prestart": "npm install",
"start": "gulp serve",
},
"devDependencies": {
"estraverse": "~4.1.0",
"gulp": "~3.9.0",
"gulp-autoprefixer": "~3.0.2",
"gulp-angular-templatecache": "~1.8.0",
"del": "~2.0.2",
"lodash": "~3.10.1",
"gulp-cssnano": "~2.1.1",
"gulp-filter": "~3.0.1",
"gulp-flatten": "~0.2.0",
"gulp-eslint": "~1.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-angular": "~0.12.0",
"gulp-load-plugins": "~0.10.0",
"gulp-size": "~2.0.0",
"gulp-uglify": "~1.4.1",
"gulp-useref": "~3.0.3",
"gulp-util": "~3.0.6",
"gulp-ng-annotate": "~1.1.0",
"gulp-replace": "~0.5.4",
"gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
"gulp-rev": "~6.0.1",
"gulp-rev-replace": "~0.4.2",
"gulp-htmlmin": "~1.3.0",
"gulp-inject": "~3.0.0",
"gulp-protractor": "~2.1.0",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.6.0",
"gulp-sass": "~2.0.4",
"gulp-angular-filesort": "~1.1.1",
"main-bower-files": "~2.9.0",
"wiredep": "~2.2.2",
"karma": "~0.13.10",
"karma-jasmine": "~0.3.6",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.1",
"phantomjs": "~1.9.18",
"karma-angular-filesort": "~1.0.0",
"karma-phantomjs-shim": "~1.2.0",
"karma-coverage": "~0.5.2",
"karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.2.0",
"browser-sync": "~2.9.11",
"browser-sync-spa": "~1.0.3",
"http-proxy-middleware": "~0.9.0",
"chalk": "~1.1.1",
"uglify-save-license": "~0.4.1",
},
"engines": {
"node": ">=0.10.0"
}
}
```

I can't find what's wrong with it . so pls help .

Comment: Remove `,` before closing object using `}`. Like ` "wiredep": "~2.2.2",`

Comment: you are right , it helps me. thank you .